# How to permanently delete resources in Python Eve after enabling soft delete?

Tags: eve

The docs at:
https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#soft-delete
clearly describe how to enable "soft delete" feature and how to restore items that are deleted.But it is not clear to me how to permanently delete suchlike items. One workaround is to implement a f. API for this purpose but I am wondering if there is already a mechanism to do this in Eve.

Thanks in advance,
Raghu

Comment: As far as I know, you can't by default. But you could create a custom endpoint in a blueprint in the flask app for that purpose. Or even an eve hook for after_delete checking a query param let's say, but that would be weird I think.

Comment: Yeah, we ended up implementing a custom endpoint.